# How can I save the output of an API call to a table in my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I am calling data from an API using HTTParty and I am able to output the data in terminal using rails runner. (I am not going to have this data available in a view, I just need to save it in the database for later use). For now my file is lib/referrers.rb

The output is returned like this:

```
{"id"=>718371286,
  "created_at"=>"2016-10-07T13:29:19Z",
  "updated_at"=>"2016-10-07T13:29:20Z",
  "tracking_code"=>"fd8382a2-2ec3-4377-9463-25f8d2e13fd1",
  "lead"=>nil,
  "url"=>
   {"id"=>90935841,
    "url"=>"http://m.facebook.com"},
  "referrer"=>{"id"=>4786600, "url"=>"http://m.facebook.com"},
  "affiliate"=>nil,
  "campaign"=>nil,
  "search_term"=>nil}
```

I would like to separate the data and save it as text, the columns in my table would be:

`uri_id, tracking_code, lead, url, referrer, affiliate, campaign, search_term, created_at, updated_at`

What I would like to know is how can I go about saving the data to my database?

Also can this be achieved without having to start the rails server every time?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this should be about as simple as possible. You just parse the json, then create a record with that data.

Comment: I suppose it would be simple once I've done it successfully a few times. For now it's pretty daunting. :)

Answer (score 1):

As a part of a rails application, I would suggest making a model just like what you described:

```
rails g model Referrer uri_id:integer tracking_code lead url referrer affiliate campaign search_term
```

And then when you get a response, instantiate a new Referrer and pass in the various parts of response to the new model.

As for your final question, you can do this in a rake task or from the rails console once you've made the model, but if you aren't going to use it as a rails app, rails is a bit heavy for your purpose, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will probably have to put it in a rake task then, which might be a bit tricky as I've had problems running rake tasks with a class for some reason. The database I'm saving to is in a rails app which is why I am using rails to do this. Sorry if I sound dumb about all this, it's my first time working with an API.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion later. Right now I'm trying to figure out why the API is suddenly not returning anything.